# How to test convergence of complex series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've been looking for examples of how complex series are tested on convergence, however I could not quite find what I wanted. So I'm asking here, how do I handle, for example:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^n}{n}$$
or
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2i)^k + 4k}{3^k + i^k}$$
?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you familiar with convergence tests for real series? Almost all the tests for real series also hold for complex series.

Comment: Simply apply them to the series in question here, and you will get convergence for a disk about some center.

Comment: Use that $i^n=\left\{\begin{align}1 & n\equiv 0,\,\text{(mod 4)}\\
i, & n\equiv 1\,\text{(mod 4)}\\
-1, & n\equiv 2\,\text{(mod 4)}\\
-i,  & n\equiv 3\,\text{(mod 4)}\end{align}\right.$ and decompose into real and imaginary part.

Comment: I have no problem testing real series on convergence. I'll try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $i^2=-1$ and so the 1st series just becomes $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}i}{n}$ which converges by alternating series test.

The second sum is absolutely convergent for similar reasons.

Comment: It looks like you had mean $i^n = (-1)^{n+1}i$. But it is not true.